# php search form and put into a table

Tags: php, search

Using this code, I do search from my database and display the result. Now its show all the result  of my table first.

Then when I search for a new Item  then its show the item. I do not want to display all result first. I want to display only searched Item.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Teacher Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Date of Birth</th>
        <th>Place of Birth</th>
        <th>Degree</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Married</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>
     <?php
     $key="";
if(isset($_POST['searchtxt']))
    $key=$_POST['searchtxt'];

if($key !="")
    $sql_sel=mysql_query("SElECT * FROM teacher_tbl WHERE f_name  like '%$key%' or l_name like '%$key%'");
else
    $sql_sel=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teacher_tbl");

$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_sel)){
$i++;
?>
  <tr >
        <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['f_name']."    ".$row['l_name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['dob'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['pob'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['degree'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['salary'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['married'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['phone'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>

    </tr>
<?php   
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Just move your `while` block inside the `if` statement and remove `else`

Comment: Oo, and welcome to SO, if you feel any of the answers helped you, then you may accept one as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following code, the search will be carried out and displayed only when you have submitted a search key:

```
<?php
$key="";
if(isset($_POST['searchtxt']) && !empty($_POST['searchtxt'])) {
    $key=$_POST['searchtxt'];
    $sql_sel=mysql_query("SElECT * FROM teacher_tbl WHERE f_name  like '%$key%' or l_name like '%$key%'");

    $i=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_sel)) {
        $i++;
        ?>
          <tr>
              <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['f_name']."    ".$row['l_name'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['dob'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['pob'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['degree'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['salary'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['married'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['phone'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
          </tr>
        <?php   
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: By the way, [avoid using the monstrous `mysql_*`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/3709765) :)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to loop through the results only if `$_POST['searchtxt']` is set.

```
 <?php
  $key=$_POST['searchtxt'];

if($key !="")
    $sql_sel=mysql_query("SElECT * FROM teacher_tbl WHERE f_name  like '%$key%' or l_name like '%$key%'");
else
    $sql_sel=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teacher_tbl");

$i=0;
if(isset($_POST['searchtxt']) && !empty($_POST['searchtxt']))
{


 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_sel)){
 $i++;
?>
  <tr >
        <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['f_name']."    ".$row['l_name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['dob'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['pob'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['degree'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['salary'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['married'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['phone'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>

    </tr>
<?php   
}
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, using this code will **always** return **all** the data, regardless of weather any search key have been provided or not!!

Comment: !empty() was what missing...thanx for the correction...ur ans does the job as well

Comment: No, not actually; the first `if` statement has set the `$sql_sel` to query the SQL command of _"SELECT * FROM teacher_tbl"_ ; because the `$key` is initially set to `''` and have been never changed!

Comment: please have a look at the if statement, I have changed it

Comment: Not that one! the first `if` statement!!

Comment: okay....i just removed the $key='', cause that doesnt make any since its been again reassigned to $_POST[''searchtxt];

Comment: Now it will work correctly, but the code still has some redundancies!

Comment: would you care to explain the redundancies?

Comment: Sure, You've firstly set the `$key=$_POST['searchtxt'];`, then checked against the `$key` using the first `if` statement, if the `$key` is empty then the statement in the `else` will be carried out, which is redundant. In the second `if` statement you've check against the emptiness of the same data you've already done once again. The suggestion is to remove the lines 2-7 and replace line 7 to exactly before the `while`, then you will get almost the exact same code as I've posted three quarters ago!!

Comment: thnx for the suggestion